# Understand how the anonymous function in ready gets called

Tags: javascript

I was just going through this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the), it describes how to create your own custom ready function in pure js. The answer is explained in great detail, I have been programming in js for a while now, but still have a problem understand the initial part of the code, Have a look at the code below again :

```
(function(funcName, baseObj) {
    // The public function name defaults to window.docReady
    // but you can pass in your own object and own function name and those will be used
    // if you want to put them in a different namespace
    funcName = funcName || "docReady";
    baseObj = baseObj || window;
    var readyList = [];
    var readyFired = false;
    var readyEventHandlersInstalled = false;

    // call this when the document is ready
    // this function protects itself against being called more than once
    function ready() {
        if (!readyFired) {
            // this must be set to true before we start calling callbacks
            readyFired = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < readyList.length; i++) {
                // if a callback here happens to add new ready handlers,
                // the docReady() function will see that it already fired
                // and will schedule the callback to run right after
                // this event loop finishes so all handlers will still execute
                // in order and no new ones will be added to the readyList
                // while we are processing the list
                readyList[i].fn.call(window, readyList[i].ctx);
            }
            // allow any closures held by these functions to free
            readyList = [];
        }
    }

    function readyStateChange() {
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            ready();
        }
    }

    // This is the one public interface
    // docReady(fn, context);
    // the context argument is optional - if present, it will be passed
    // as an argument to the callback
    baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
        // if ready has already fired, then just schedule the callback
        // to fire asynchronously, but right away
        if (readyFired) {
            setTimeout(function() {callback(context);}, 1);
            return;
        } else {
            // add the function and context to the list
            readyList.push({fn: callback, ctx: context});
        }
        // if document already ready to go, schedule the ready function to run
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            setTimeout(ready, 1);
        } else if (!readyEventHandlersInstalled) {
            // otherwise if we don't have event handlers installed, install them
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                // first choice is DOMContentLoaded event
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, false);
                // backup is window load event
                window.addEventListener("load", ready, false);
            } else {
                // must be IE
                document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", readyStateChange);
                window.attachEvent("onload", ready);
            }
            readyEventHandlersInstalled = true;
        }
    };
})("docReady", window);
```

and i am calling the code like so:

```
docReady(function() {
        alert('hello');
  }, window);
```

My question is, how can you call a anonymous function , like so ? .. i am totally confused :(

How on earth does even the below code work ?

```
docReady(function() {
        alert('hello');
  }, window);
```

I mean there is no explicit docReady function defined , like so:

```
  docReady function (param1, param2);
```

all i see is docReady being passed as a parameter to the anonymous function ?

Comment: `baseObj[funcName]` declares the function (edit: I made an answer to make it clearer).

Comment: What he said. In the above code, `baseObj` is `window`, and `funcName` is `"docReady"`, so it's `window["docReady"] = function()...`, which is the same as `window.docReady = function() ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
```

is equivalent to

```
window["docReady"] = function(callback, context) {
```

It declares the function as a property of `window`, the global object, which means you can call it with

```
window["docReady"](function() {
    alert('hello');
}, window);
```

or with

```
window.docReady(function() {
    alert('hello');
}, window);
```

or even

```
docReady(function() {
        alert('hello');
}, window);
```

as properties of the global object are also variables of the global scope (and any scope inside until shadowed).

Answer (score 2):

The key bit is `baseObj[funcName] = function`

at this point `baseObj` is (or at least can be) `window`, and `funcName` is (or can be) `docReady`.

So at that point it adds a function to `window` (global) called "docReady"

`window` and "docReady" are being passed as default parameters on the last line

`})("docReady", window);`

which enter the function at the top as parameters `(function(funcName, baseObj) {`

**N.B.** When I say `baseObj` is (or at least can be) `window`, that's because you can override this value, this line:

```
funcName = funcName || "docReady";
baseObj = baseObj || window;
```

set's `funcName` to "docReady" and `baseObj` if an alternative isnt provided, that means that you can change them if you like, so if the last line was changed to `})("getReady", myObject);` the function would be called getReady and be added to the `myObject`, not the global `window`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the code wrong.

Check these lines:

```
(function(funcName, baseObj) {
    ...
    baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
        ...
    };
    ...
})("docReady", window);
```

It is adding a new property to the `baseObj`, which in this case is `window`. That property is the function you call. The `docReady`. Everything that is global doesn't need to be called like `window.something`. That's why you use `docReady`.